# Django : One model has two foreign keys is this the right approach in this case

Tags: django, django-models

I am currently learning about Django Models. Here is my current situation. I have three models

```
1-Patient_Names
2-Patient_Responses
3-Doctor_Questions
```

Now here is the relationship there will be multiple patients which will be represented by the model `Patient_Names`. Now each patient will have specific responses to the questions asked by a doctor these responses are represented by the model `Patient_Responses`. Because of this the `Patient_Responses` model will have a field that is a foreignKey to the `Patient_Names` model.Also since the responses will be for the questions from the model `Doctor_Questions`the Patient_Response has another field that is foreignKey to the model  `Doctor_Questions`. Is this the right approach ? Can a model have two foreign keys?

```
Patient_Names                 Doctor_Questions
   |                                  |
   |---------Patient_Responses -------|       
                 |
                 pname = models.ForeignKey(Patient_Names)
                 doctor_questions = models.ForeignKey(Doctor_Questions)
```

Comment: Are the Doctor_Questions always the same? Then this absolutely makes sense. It quite often happens that a model has more than one ForeignKey.

Comment: The doctor_questions are a list of questions a doctor might ask.

Comment: The approach is ok. The model can have different ForeignKeys as well as M2M fields. Just continue and create a test database to see how it works together!

Comment: Suggestion: this could be moved/copied to the documentation on SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have actually created here is a Many to Many relationship and in django it's supported with the [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

**case 1, Patient_Responses has only the two foreign keys.**

You don't need this model. Simply delete it and add a ManyToManyField on one of the remaining models to simplify your code and to gain access to the set of features provided by this field

```
class Patient_Names(models.Model):
    ...
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Doctor_Questions)
```

**case 2, Patient_Responses has fields other than the two foreign keys.**

Now you can't delete the Patient_Responses model but you can still unlock the ManyToManyFields benefits by declaring it as a Through Model

```
questions = models.ManyToManyField(Doctor_Questions, through='Patient_Responses')
```

Comment: Thanks . I am not really familiar with ManyToManyField. In my case Ill have other fields so I will have to go with case 2. Can you tell me what the query would look like if I want to retrieve a record from Patient_Responses when I have an instance of Doctor_Questions and Patient_Names  ?

Comment: when you have one of each?

Comment: yes when I have an instance of a model of Doctor_Questions and an instance of Patient_Names model. How do I get the corresponding Patient_Responses if the relationship is  ManyToManyField assuming there is a separate model for Patient_Responses with some other fields (case 2)?

Comment: In case 2, its really straight forward Patient_Responses.objects.filter(pname=patient, doctor_quetions=doctor)

Comment: I really urge you to read that document page on Many  to Many if you don't you will end up writing a lot of code you don't need to write (ie duplicating the funcionality already provided by django)

Comment: I definitely will

Comment: Though here is what I dont understand. Since I am already going to have a separate model for `Patient_Responses` either way (using two foreign keys or using many to many). I really dont understand how using ManyToManyField will help me write comparatively less code. I will definitely read more on ManyToManyField  though.

Comment: on this particular instance because you are having a through model there wasn't a need to query on Doctor or Patient models to get there. I am still not sure why you need that model at all since it doesn't seem to contain any other fields

Comment: As i mentioned earlier it will contain other fields like "response" and "Time of response" etc

Comment: I still havent had a chance to test this out. Once I test this out Ill mark it as answered. Thanks for taking the time to answer and clarify

Comment: Certainly, certainly. But I think "Is this the right approach ? Can a model have two foreign keys?" has adequately been answered everything else is supplementary