# How Do I Represent Student-Lecturer Relationship in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

So I'm trying to make a web app that is meant to aid interaction between students and teachers.

However, I need to know how to structure the model of relationships in Django. Here are 2 things you should know:

1. A teacher can have many students (users) under him or her.
2. A student can only have one user as his teacher.

In other words, teachers are meant to have as many students as possible, while each student can only have one teacher.

How should I represent this in Django? And what's the best way to manage this relationship? For the latter question, I'm thinking about creating a class that looks like this:

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
     ##student and lecturer models shall inherit the User class; hence, the


     student = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'lecturer_set')
     lecturer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'student_set')

     class Meta:
         unique_together = ('student', 'lecturer')
```

PS: I know the above class might be wrong. Just trying to explain what I need to implement in the Relationship class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django : One model has two foreign keys is this the right approach in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715273/django-one-model-has-two-foreign-keys-is-this-the-right-approach-in-this-case)

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard one-to-many relationship, which is represented in Django by a simple ForeignKey.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
```

You don't need the Relationship model at all.